# Is there a general poset representation that specializes to power set lattices in case of finite boolean algebras?

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebras_canonically_defined#Representation_theorems) that every finite, complemented, distributive lattice is isomorphic to a power set lattice.

Is there a general order preserving mapping from a poset $P$ to a set inclusion poset $S$, such that

1. When $P$ is a distributive lattice, the meet and join in $S$ are set intersection and union.
2. When $P$ is also complemented, $S$ is complemented by set complement.
3. When $P$ is also finite, $S$ is a power set?

Which is the more general construction of this kind?

Comment: You're looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_representation_theorem. Not that it's the answer to the questions that you actually asked, but it is the correct generalization of the representation of Boolean algebras to posets.

Comment: @Pilcrow It says that Birkhoff's representation doesn't necessarily work in the infinite case. If I understood well, there is another one, the Stone's representation, that works for the infinite case, but requires complementation. My questions are: does Stone's always reduce to a power set in the finite case? Do you know if there is a generalization to the both infinite and non complemented case?

Comment: The representation of arbitrary distibutive lattices is covered by the Priestley duality, which restricts to the Stone duality in the Boolean case and the Birkhoff duality in the finite case. Both restrict to the representation of finite Boolean algebras as powersets of finite sets in the finite Boolean case. In other words, the representation of (finite) Boolean algebras in terms of unordered structures extends naturally to a representation of (finite) distributive lattices in terms of ordered structures.